# I cant solve this E/Environment: initForCurrentUser:userId= 0

Tags: java, android

I'm newbie in android programming and I tried to create this apps, but I always stuck and have this problem,

```
E/Environment: initForCurrentUser:userId= 0
```

Can anyone help me?. This is my code,

Database.java

```
package com.example.acer.drcoffee;

import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton; import 
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.os.Bundle; import 
android.view.View; import android.widget.ImageView; import 
android.widget.TextView; import android.widget.Toast;

import com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton; import 
com.example.acer.drcoffee.Database.Database; import 
com.example.acer.drcoffee.Model.Food; import 
com.example.acer.drcoffee.Model.Order; import 
com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot; import 
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError; import 
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference; import 
com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase; import 
com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener; 
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class FoodDetail extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView food_name,food_price,food_description;
ImageView food_image;
CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;
FloatingActionButton btn_Cart;
ElegantNumberButton number_Button;

String foodId="";

FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference foods;

Food currentFood;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_detail);

    //init Firebase
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    foods = database.getReference("Foods");

    //init View
    number_Button = (ElegantNumberButton)findViewById(R.id.numberButton);
    btn_Cart = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.btnCart);

    btn_Cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new Database(getBaseContext()).addToCart(new Order(
                foodId,
                currentFood.getName(),
                number_Button.getNumber(),
                currentFood.getPrice(),
                currentFood.getDiscount()
        ));

        Toast.makeText(FoodDetail.this,"Telah Ditambahkan         !!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

food_name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.foodName);
food_price = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.foodPrice);
food_description = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.foodDescription);  
food_image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgFood);

//Buat style untuk appbar di value/style
collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout)findViewById(R.id.collapsing);
collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.ExpandedAppBar);
collapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.CollapsedAppBar);

//get food ID from Intent
if (getIntent() != null)
    foodId = getIntent().getStringExtra("FoodId");
if (!foodId.isEmpty())
{
    getDetailFood(foodId);
}
}

private void getDetailFood(String foodId) {
foods.child(foodId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        currentFood = dataSnapshot.getValue(Food.class);

        //set image
        Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(currentFood.getImage())
                .into(food_image);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(currentFood.getName());
        food_price.setText(currentFood.getPrice());
        food_name.setText(currentFood.getName());
        food_description.setText(currentFood.getDescription());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
}
}
```

Order.java

```
package com.example.acer.drcoffee.Model;

/** * Created by acer on 09/12/2017. */

public class Order { private String ProductId; private String ProductName;             private String Quantity; private String Price; private String Discount;

public Order() {
}

public Order(String productId, String productName, String quantity, String price, String discount) {
ProductId = productId;
ProductName = productName;
Quantity = quantity;
Price = price;
Discount = discount;
}

public String getProductId() {
return ProductId;
}

public void setProductId(String productId) {
ProductId = productId;
}

public String getProductName() {
return ProductName;
}

public void setProductName(String productName) {
ProductName = productName;
}

public String getQuantity() {
return Quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
Quantity = quantity;
}

public String getPrice() {
return Price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
Price = price;
}

public String getDiscount() {
return Discount;
}

public void setDiscount(String discount) {
Discount = discount;
}
}
```

FoodDetail.java

```
package com.example.acer.drcoffee;

import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle; import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.ImageView; import android.widget.TextView; 
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton; 
import com.example.acer.drcoffee.Database.Database; 
import com.example.acer.drcoffee.Model.Food; 
import com.example.acer.drcoffee.Model.Order; 
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot; 
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError; 
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference; 
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase; 
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener; 
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class FoodDetail extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView food_name,food_price,food_description;
ImageView food_image;
CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;
FloatingActionButton btn_Cart;
ElegantNumberButton number_Button;

String foodId="";

FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference foods;

Food currentFood;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_detail);

//init Firebase
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
foods = database.getReference("Foods");

//init View
number_Button = (ElegantNumberButton)findViewById(R.id.numberButton);
btn_Cart = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.btnCart);

btn_Cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new Database(getBaseContext()).addToCart(new Order(
                foodId,
                currentFood.getName(),
                number_Button.getNumber(),
                currentFood.getPrice(),
                currentFood.getDiscount()
        ));

        Toast.makeText(FoodDetail.this,"Telah Ditambahkan     !!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

food_name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.foodName);
food_price = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.foodPrice);
food_description = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.foodDescription);
food_image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgFood);

//Buat style untuk appbar di value/style
collapsingToolbarLayout =     (CollapsingToolbarLayout)findViewById(R.id.collapsing);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.ExpandedAppBar);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.CollapsedAppBar);

//get food ID from Intent
if (getIntent() != null)
    foodId = getIntent().getStringExtra("FoodId");
if (!foodId.isEmpty())
{
    getDetailFood(foodId);
}
}

private void getDetailFood(String foodId) {
foods.child(foodId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        currentFood = dataSnapshot.getValue(Food.class);

        //set image
        Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(currentFood.getImage())
                .into(food_image);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(currentFood.getName());
        food_price.setText(currentFood.getPrice());
        food_name.setText(currentFood.getName());
        food_description.setText(currentFood.getDescription());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
}
}
```

I've tried to solve it by myself, but it already 2 weeks and I still don't know how to solve it, so please anyone help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should recreate your project. Make new project then create each class one by one and run the application as you create each class or you can set breakpoints and debug your project. Also look at this link it may help you.
[This link represent the class that initiate the current user](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/0e2d281/core/java/android/os/Environment.java)